# How to access heap start address and heap base address within c function

Tags: c, assembly, cortex-m

For my own dynamic memory allocation implementation of malloc, I want to access the heap base address and heap limit address during run time. I know they are exported as globals in my startup.s file. How can I access these addresses?
Target platform is ARM Cortex-M4 with GCC.

Symbols declared with *.globl* are known to the linker and should be accessable using the *extern* symbol within c code. But using this method, I get values that differ from the values within the generated *.map* file.

Here are the heap symbols defined in the startup.s file:

```
#ifdef __HEAP_SIZE
    .equ        Heap_Size, __HEAP_SIZE
#else
    .equ        Heap_Size, 0x00000C00
#endif
    .globl      __HeapBase
    .globl      __HeapLimit
__HeapBase:
    .if Heap_Size
    .space      Heap_Size
    .endif
    .size       __HeapBase, . - __HeapBase
__HeapLimit:
    .size       __HeapLimit, . - __HeapLimit

    .section    .vectors
    .align      2
    .globl      __Vectors
```

Here is my access within my c function:

```c
extern volatile __HeapBase;
extern volatile __HeapLimit;

static void heaptest(void) {
    uint32_t limit;
    uint32_t base;

    base = __HeapBase;
    limit = __HeapLimit;
}
```

Debugging this code, I get other addresses than specified in the generated *.map* file:

```
.heap           0x200317a0    0x40000
                0x200317a0                __HeapBase = .
...
                0x200717a0                __HeapLimit = .
...
```

So I expect the output to be *0x200317a0* for *__HeapBase* and *0x200717a0* for *__HeapLimit*, but the actual outputs I get are *0xf377aaa2* and *0xac69254*.

Comment: How are you compiling, linking and running this? Add the rest of the needed code to have a [minimal and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (emphasis on *reproducible*).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exported symbols are addresses, but the C compiler dereferences them for you. To get the address back, you need to apply the address-of operator `&`, that is `void* base = &__HeapBase;` should work. As written, you are actually fetching the first item from the heap.

Answer (score 5):

Declare them as **`extern char __HeapBase[];`** because in C the name of an array object converts to a pointer, while names of other objects are implicitly dereferenced.

Maybe also use `#define HEAPBASE ((void*)__HeapBase)` to make it convenient to use the name.  Or cast it to `(uintptr_t)` or whatever.

Having a separate global `void *base = &__HeapBase;` would be less good: `base` is not a compile-time-constant value because it's not even declared as `const`.  Code that uses it will have to load a pointer from static storage, instead of having a link-time constant address they can use directly.